# When retrieving data from firebase in Kotlin, the list returns empty

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

first situation:
[image: first situation]

second situation
[image: second situation]

I am making an application in Kotlin and I save my data in firebase and get the data from there. The function I use to save data to firebase is the `saveArea(1)` function written in the code blog.

When I want to retrieve the data I saved here, I use my `fetchData(2)` function and I can retrieve my data. However, the function I use to retrieve all data of all users is `fetchArea(3)`. After my function runs, an empty list appears.

When I opened the data in the Firestore console, I saw a message like this (photo 1):

> this document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshot

Then, I clicked on the section that says Add field and I added some data and then deleted it and saw the text in photo 2:

> This document has no data.

After doing this, my `fetchArea(3)` function worked and I was able to get all the data under Users.

Am I doing the wrong query or is it my saving mat while saving data wrong?

```
class FireBaseSourceImpl @Inject constructor(private val database: FirebaseFirestore) : FireBaseSource {


    override suspend fun saveArea(dataModel: DataModel): Result<Unit> {

        return kotlin.runCatching {

            val post = hashMapOf(
                "message" to dataModel.message,
                "title" to dataModel.title,
                "photoUrl" to dataModel.photoUrl,
                "timeStamp" to dataModel.timestamp

            )

            database.collection("Users").document(dataModel.currentUser)
                .collection("construcitonName").document(dataModel.constructionArea).set(post)
                .await()
        }
    }


    override suspend fun fetchData(
        currentUser: String, constructionName: String
    ): Result<List<DataModel>> {
        return kotlin.runCatching {
            val dataModelList = mutableListOf<DataModel>()

            val documentSnapshot =
                database.collection("Users").document(currentUser).collection("construcitonName")
                    .document(constructionName).get().await()

            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                val data = documentSnapshot.data
                val message = data?.get("message") as? String ?: ""
                val title = data?.get("title") as? String ?: ""
                val photoUrl = data?.get("photoUrl") as? String ?: ""
                val timestamp = data?.get("timeStamp") as? Long ?: 0L

                val retrievedDataModel = DataModel(
                    message, title, photoUrl, timestamp, currentUser, constructionName
                )
                dataModelList.add(retrievedDataModel)
            }

            dataModelList.toList()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun fetchArea(): Result<List<ConstructionName>> {
        return kotlin.runCatching {
            val constructionNames = mutableListOf<ConstructionName>()

            val usersSnapshot = database.collection("Users")
                .get().await()

            if (usersSnapshot.isEmpty){
                Log.d("FirebaseDebug", "usersSnapshot is empty")
            }

            for (userDocument in usersSnapshot.documents) {
                val userId = userDocument.id
                val constructionsSnapshot = userDocument.reference.collection("construcitonName").get().await()

                for (constructionDocument in constructionsSnapshot.documents) {
                    val data = constructionDocument.data
                    val message = data?.get("message") as? String ?: ""
                    val title = data?.get("title") as? String ?: ""
                    val photoUrl = data?.get("photoUrl") as? String ?: ""
                    val timestamp = data?.get("timeStamp") as? Number ?: 0

                    val constructionName = ConstructionName(
                        userId,
                        constructionDocument.id,
                        message,
                        title,
                        photoUrl,
                        timestamp.toLong()
                    )
                    constructionNames.add(constructionName)
                }
            }

            constructionNames.toList()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `dataModel.currentUser` inside the reference?

Comment: equal to auth id in firebase like this 
val currentUser = viewModel.currentUser?.uid.toString()

Comment: Have you tried to log the real value?

Comment: Yes, I logged it in the saveArea function, which saves the data. Same as what I see in firebase
             Log.d("FirebaseDebug", dataModel.currentUser)
             Log.d("FirebaseDebug", dataModel.constructionArea)

Comment: What is this question different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77500309/the-function-does-not-work-when-retrieving-data-from-firebase-in-kotlin)?

Comment: I just edited the question, the problem is the same. I have removed the other question, thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: ok Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I edited my save function as written below. I had to enter information, even if it was empty, into the documents I used when creating the reference. Otherwise I was getting an error like "Non-existent ancestor documents".

```
override suspend fun saveArea(dataModel: DataModel): Result<Unit> {
return kotlin.runCatching {
    val post = hashMapOf(
        "message" to dataModel.message,
        "title" to dataModel.title,
        "photoUrl" to dataModel.photoUrl,
        "timeStamp" to dataModel.timestamp
    )

    val currentUserRef = database.collection("Users").document(dataModel.currentUser)
    val constructionSiteRef = currentUserRef.collection("construcitonName").document(dataModel.constructionArea)

    //Create the parent document
    currentUserRef.set(hashMapOf("dummyField" to "dummyValue")).await()
    constructionSiteRef.set(hashMapOf("dummyField" to "dummyValue")).await()

    val postsRef = constructionSiteRef.collection("posts").document("20231117")

    postsRef.set(post).await()
}
```

}

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console?authuser=0&_gl=1*11pt0xi*_ga*MjAzNjU4MjAwOS4xNjk0ODY2MDMy*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcwMDIzNTY3Mi44MS4xLjE3MDAyNDIwODAuMzkuMC4w#non-existent_ancestor_documents